# How to append interval offset ater timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 columns 
1) from_date .  (timestamp without timezone) 
2)to_date      (timestamp without timezone)
3) utc_offset   (interval)

Expected output :
suppose I have date in this format 
`2018-12-31T23:00:00` and the interval is `0 years 0 mons 0 days -5 hours 0 mins -0.00 secs`

then I want to show date as `2018-12-31T23:00:00-05:00`

when the offset is `0 years 0 mons 0 days +5 hours 0 mins +0.00 secs`
then the date should be `2018-12-31T23:00:00+05:00`

current solution :

```
select concat(cast('2019-02-28 23:59:59':: timestamp with time zone as 
timestamp(0))::text , coalesce(to_char('0 years 0 mons 0 days -5 hours 
0 mins 0.00 secs'::interval,'HH:MM') ,'00:00'))
```

this is returning me correct result `2019-02-28 23:59:59-05:00`

but when the interval changes

```
 select concat(cast('2019-02-28 23:59:59':: timestamp with time zone 
 as 
 timestamp(0))::text , coalesce(to_char('0 years 0 mons 0 days +5 
 hours 
 0 mins 0.00 secs'::interval,'HH:MM') ,'00:00'))
```

Then the result is 
`2019-02-28 23:59:5905:00`

how do i get the result as `2019-02-28 23:59:59+05:00` when offset is ahead 
and `2019-02-28 23:59:59-05:00` when offset is behind

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea but is there no way you can store the timestamps as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`?

```
SELECT '2019-05-21 02:02:20'::timestamp at time zone a.abbrev 
FROM
(
    SELECT abbrev
    FROM pg_timezone_names 
    WHERE utc_offset = '-05:00:00'
    LIMIT 1
) a
;
```

---

```
timezone
2019-05-21 08:02:20+01
```

---

Or as a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestamp_tz(ts timestamp, off interval)
RETURNS SETOF timestamptz
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT ts AT TIME ZONE a.abbrev 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT abbrev
        FROM pg_timezone_names 
        WHERE utc_offset = off
        LIMIT 1
    ) a
    ;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with J Spratt that it would be better to just store timestamp with time zone, although it would not be possible to recreate the offset from that alone.

Here's a function that can do this formatting.  Basically, set the local session time zone to the offset and format from there.

```
create or replace function format_date(start timestamp, utc_offset interval)
returns text
set timezone from current
AS
$$
DECLARE
  out text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SET local time zone INTERVAL ' || quote_literal(utc_offset) || ' HOUR TO MINUTE';
  select to_char(start at time zone utc_offset, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSOF') into out;
  RETURN out;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
# select format_date('2018-12-31T23:00:00'::timestamp, interval '+5 hours');
      format_date
------------------------
 2018-12-31 23:00:00+05
(1 row)
# select format_date('2018-12-31T23:00:00'::timestamp, interval '-5 hours');
      format_date
------------------------
 2018-12-31 23:00:00-05
(1 row)
```